# Instance of tuple has no member (pylint no-member) in enum class

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums, pylint

I am getting the following errors from pylint when using the members "value" and "equals" from an enum class:
    "code": "no-member"
    "message": "Instance of 'tuple' has no 'value' member"
Versions:
pylint 2.3.1
astroid 2.2.5
Python 3.6.3

The code is executed as expected. I am just wondering if there might be something I am doing wrong (I am not a pro python programmer), or if there is a more "pythonic" way to achieve the same result:

```
from enum import Enum

class DefaultEnum(Enum):

    def __new__(self,val,_name,_type):
        obj = object.__new__(self)
        obj._value_ = val
        obj._publicName = _name
        obj._type = _type
        return obj

    def __str__(self):
        return self._publicName

    def equals(self,_string):
        return _string == str(self)

class GlobalEnum(DefaultEnum):
    TRUE = 0,'True',str()
    FALSE = 1,'False',str()


GlobalEnum.TRUE.value
>> 0
GlobalEnum.TRUE.equals('True')
>> True
repr(GlobalEnum.TRUE)
>> <GlobalEnum.TRUE: 0>
```

I am currently using the "# pylint: disable=no-member" comment to disable the warning, but I would prefer not to do this... The same goes for white-listing the class as I still would like pylint to report other findings.

Comment: Is there a reason why you use `__new__` instead of `__init__` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To answer your main question:

1. `pylint` [doesn't recognize](http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/messages:e1101) dynamically-created attributes, and
2. `Enum` is "special" in a [number of ways](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#how-are-enums-different), one of them being that an Enum's members are actually instances of the `enum` class:

```
    from enum import Enum

    class MyEnum(Enum):
        val1 = 0

    print(type(MyEnum.val1)) # <enum 'MyEnum'>


    class MyClass:
        val1 = 0

    print(type(MyClass.val1)) # <class 'int'>
```

That is, when you set `TRUE` in your `GlobalEnum` class, Python is converting `TRUE` into an instance of `GlobalEnum`, but pylint doesn't understand this, and since it looks like `GlobalEnum.TRUE` is being assigned a tuple value, pylint thinks it's a tuple, which has no "value" member.

To answer if there's a more "pythonic" way to achieve the same result, I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but it looks like there are some weird things you're doing.  For example:

1. `__new__()` gets passed a *class* as its first argument, but you're calling it "self," which by (near-)universal convention refers to an *instance*, which is very confusing to read.  Typically one would call it `cls`.
2. Single leading underscores ("`_name`", "`_type`") by convention are usually used to denote "private" members, so it's going to be confusing to most readers to use them in function signatures.  If you want to use a reserved word as a parameter name, a common convention is to use a trailing underscore (e.g., "`type_`", "`exec_`").
3. I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with your "`_type`" attribute, but right now both `GlobalEnum.TRUE` and `GlobalEnum.FALSE` will return an empty string as their `_type`, because `str()` returns a string instance, and without args the string will be empty.  If you want it to return the `str` *type*, you should set it to `str` (without the parentheses).
4. I *think* what you're trying to do is to create an enum whose values will evaluate to True when compared against either an int or a string that you specify in the definition.  In that case, instead of a user-defined `equals()` method (which you'll almost certainly forget to use at some point), you can override the built-in `__eq__()` magic method so that you can use the usual `==` operator instead:

```
from enum import Enum


class BaseEnum(Enum):

    def __init__(self, int_value, str_value):
        self._value_ = int_value
        self.str_value = str_value

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return other == self.value or other == self.str_value


class MyEnum(BaseEnum):
    TRUE = 0, 'True'
    FALSE = 1, 'False'


print(MyEnum.TRUE == 0)  # True
print(MyEnum.TRUE == 'True')  # True
a = MyEnum.TRUE
print(a == MyEnum.TRUE) # True

print(MyEnum.TRUE.value)  # 0
print(MyEnum.TRUE.str_value)  # 'True'
```

[Note that `str_value` above is just a regular class property, meaning it can be set.  To make it read-only, you can use a [property decorator](https://stackabuse.com/the-python-property-decorator/) without a setter.]